# c:forEach Iteration

Tags: jsp, jstl

Following is the rough iteration I am Trying:

```
<c:forEach  items="${row.myList}" var="mainRow" varStatus="table">
        ${ table.first? '<table>':'<tr><td><strong>${mainRow.heading}</strong></td></tr>'}

            <c:forEach items="${mainRow.values}" var="value" >
             <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox"  value="${value}"/>${value}</td>
              </tr>
            </c:forEach>
             ${ table.last? '</table>':''}
        </c:forEach>
```

Problem is that it printing ${mainRow.heading} instead of the attribute value.
Also what else options are there table.? like first, last. Is there any docs fot it?

Comment: In El you have an option for isFirst or isLast to check First and Last elements, You may go through http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
${ table.first? '<table>':'<tr><td><strong>${mainRow.heading}</strong></td></tr>'}
```

The above expression does not what you want, because you embedded an EL expression inside a String literal inside an EL expression. What you want is

```
${table.first? '<table>' : '<tr><td><strong>' + mainRow.heading + '</strong></td></tr>'}
```

or

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${table.first}">
        <table>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <tr><td><strong>${mainRow.heading}</strong></td></tr>
    </c:otherwise
</c:choose>
```

which is longer, but more readable, IMO.

Comment: Does the `+` work for string concatenation in EL?   Also why don't you have problems with unmatched <table> </table> elements etc?

Comment: Thanks for solution, the second one worked and is more readable.

Comment: Also, if you can suggest more, the checkboxes now getting displayed are in one column only. Can we have two checkboxes in a row. I am trying various combination with begin,end,step...

Comment: I directly changed in jsp (inthe deployed path) ,it worked fine. I am now changing in workspace , my RAD showing error in <table> line saying no end tag. Similar kind of error in </table>. How to remove such error?

Comment: @Dhananjay: your editor is confused because the HTML tags are not balanced, but what matters is that the generated HTML is valid.

Comment: @sbk: to be honest, I didn't test it. If it doesn't work, then concat will have to be used, or the second solution.

Comment: @JBNizet ahh. I'd thought I'd missed something in the doco about +.  Thanks for your honesty.

Answer (score 1):

In your code snippet, `'<tr><td><strong>${mainRow.heading}</strong></td></tr>'` is a just a string as far as JSP is concerned, hence the no substitution.  Use this instead

```
${ table.first? '&lt;table&gt;':'<tr><td><strong>'.concat(mainRow.heading).concat('</strong></td></tr>') }
```

(I  had to use html entities to avoid unmatched tags.)

The other varStatus options are docced here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html